# Google Charts doesn't get updated when Firebase data has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, firebase, google-visualization

I've managed to hook my Firebase up to Google Charts which works great, but I'm struggling in how to show a simple message saying 'no data' if there is no data that evaluates to a simple if else expression I've declared.

For example, I have a Firebase data value of 'NA' set up for a single user, which would in theory mean the chart will not show by default and the error message would show up on page load and at any point this changes back to this value. However, this is not the case and the only way to trigger it is by clicking the 3D button I've set up in the HTML file. Also, when the Firebase data changes to a value greater than zero, the error message still shows.

Here is my code:

**JS File**

```
var displayMode = true;

$scope.statistics = function () {
    $mdSidenav('left').close();
    $state.go('statistics');
    $timeout(function () {
        setUpChart();
        var timer;
        $(window).on('resize', function () {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                setUpChart();
            }, 250);
        });
    });
};

function setUpChart() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '//www.google.com/jsapi',
        dataType: 'script',
        cache: true,
        success: function () {
            google.load('visualization', '1', {
                'packages': ['corechart'],
                'callback': drawChart
            });
        }
    });

    function drawChart() {

        // This links to my Firebase url
        userRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {

            var pass = 0;
            var fail = 0;

            snapshot.forEach(function (snapshot) {
                var userResults = snapshot.val();
                if (userResults.passFail === 'Pass') {
                    pass = pass + 1;
                }
                if (userResults.passFail === 'Fail') {
                    fail = fail + 1;
                }
            });

            if (pass === 0 && fail === 0) {
                console.log('No data: ' + pass + ' & ' + fail);
                $scope.error = true;
                $scope.errorMessage = 'No user data available, please try  
                again later.';
            } else {
                console.log('Is data: ' + pass + ' & ' + fail);
                $scope.error = false;
                $scope.errorMessage = null;
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('string', 'Result');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Delegates');
                data.addRows([
                    ['Pass', pass],
                    ['Fail', fail]
                ]);

                var options = {
                    'is3D': displayMode,
                    'chartArea': {'width': '100%', 'height': '80%'},
                    'legend': {'position': 'top', 'alignment': 'center'}
                };

                var chart = new 
         google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pieChart'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }

        });

    }

}

// Changes chart type to 3D or top view on a butto click
$scope.chartFormat = function () {
    if (displayMode == true)
        displayMode = false;
    else
        displayMode = true;
    setUpChart();
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 100px; padding-bottom: 50px">

<button data-ng-model="displayType" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto"
        data-ng-click="displayType=displayType ? false : true;  
        chartFormat()"
        class="btn btn-default btn-md" type="button"><i class="material-
        icons">3d_rotation</i></button>

<div data-ng-if="error" class="alert alert-danger">
   <span data-ng-if="errorMessage" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">  
   </span><strong> {{errorMessage}}</strong>
</div>

<div id="pieChart" style="display: block; margin: 0 
auto; width: 100%; height: 500px"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Note that code external to angular core that updates scope needs to notify angular to run digest.

Comment: Can you please explain by example in this as I've not used this method before?

Comment: use `$scope.$apply()`

Answer (score 1):

If anyone experiences a similar problem to mine above, simply add **data-ng-init="function_name_here()"** to the error message div that you want to show in your html if your Google Chart has no data.

Never thought of this before, but works a treat now and dynamically displays the error message in my case and removes the message if data exists!

Answer (score 0):

Your code in `userRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {` runs asynchronously whenever the data in Firebase changes. At that moment AngularJS is not expecting changes to the `$scope`, so it doesn't see them.

The solution is to make AngularJS aware of the fact that you changed the `$scope` either by calling `$scope.$apply()` as charlieftl suggested or by wrapping it in a `$timeout()` so that it gets picked up in the next digest cycle:

```
userRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
    $timeout(function() {
        var pass = 0;
        var fail = 0;

        snapshot.forEach(function (snapshot) {
            var userResults = snapshot.val();
            if (userResults.passFail === 'Pass') {
                pass = pass + 1;
            }
            if (userResults.passFail === 'Fail') {
                fail = fail + 1;
            }
        });

        if (pass === 0 && fail === 0) {
            console.log('No data: ' + pass + ' & ' + fail);
            $scope.error = true;
            $scope.errorMessage = 'No user data available, please try  
            again later.';
        } else {
            console.log('Is data: ' + pass + ' & ' + fail);
            $scope.error = false;
            $scope.errorMessage = null;
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Result');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Delegates');
            data.addRows([
                ['Pass', pass],
                ['Fail', fail]
            ]);

            var options = {
                'is3D': displayMode,
                'chartArea': {'width': '100%', 'height': '80%'},
                'legend': {'position': 'top', 'alignment': 'center'}
            };

            var chart = new 
     google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pieChart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for the response. I did try this method before and have just tried again to see if it would work. However, it's throwing an error as 'Error: Container is not defined', which the following code refers to Pp@https://www.google.com/uds/api/visualization...

Comment: Ignore my past comment, I had a 'data-ng-if' in my html for the pie chart, which I've now removed. However,it's still not working by displaying the error message. This is only the case on first page load, which it should show the message. If I manually change the Firebase data value to 'Pass' for example, it will all start working as I want it to